# Capitalising titles

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

I have tried to capitalise the first letter of words in my bibliography titles by doing `title = {Taniyama-{S}himura {C}onjecture}` and this has worked for me so far. However, on my final reference, which is a `\nocite{}` reference, this has not worked. My final reference, where the problem is, is: `title = {Wiles's {P}roof of {F}ermat's {L}ast {T}heorem}`, and I cannot see why this wouldn't work this time.

My full BiBTeX file is as follows, and its name is References:

```
@misc{Polygonal-Number,
    author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    title = {Polygonal {N}umber},
    year = {2017},
    url = {http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonalNumber.html},
  }

@misc{Epsilon-Conjecture,
    author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    title = {Epsilon {C}onjecture},
    year = {2017},
    url = {http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EpsilonConjecture.html},
    }

@misc{Modularity-Theorem,
    author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    title = {Taniyama-{S}himura {C}onjecture},
    year = {2017},
    url = {http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Taniyama-ShimuraConjecture.html},
    }

@misc{Wiles'-Proof-of-Fermat's-Last-Theorem,
    author = {K. Rubin and A. Silverberg},
    title = "Wiles{'}s {P}roof of {F}ermat's {L}ast {T}heorem",
    year = {2018},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem&oldid=830454832},
    }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I am using `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`

Comment: The titles are all capitalized for me... Try enclosing the whole title in braces, not only the first letter. BibTeX will not change what it finds within a second pair of braces. For example: `title={{Wiles's Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem}}`. Also, you have to escape the "spacial" characters of the url field. Mainly because of this last entry. The `%` has to be `\%`, the `_`, `\_`, and the `&` has to be `\&`. Like this: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wiles\%27s\_proof\_of\_Fermat\%27s\_Last\_Theorem\&oldid=830454832`.

Comment: This works for me. Did you remember the include the `url` or `hyperref` packages? You shouldn't need to do what @PhelypeOleinik suggests with the `\%` and `\&` if so.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your `.bib` slightly, but even without the changes, it works fine as long as you include the `url` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

% filecontents is only for this example, you don't need it.
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{Polygonal-Number,
    author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    title = {{Polygonal Number}},
    year = 2017,
    url = {http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonalNumber.html},
  }

@misc{Epsilon-Conjecture,
    author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    title = {{Epsilon Conjecture}},
    year = 2017,
    url = {http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EpsilonConjecture.html},
    }

@misc{Modularity-Theorem,
    author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    title = {{Taniyama--Shimura Conjecture}},
    year = 2017,
    url = {http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Taniyama-ShimuraConjecture.html},
    }

@misc{Wiles'-Proof-of-Fermat's-Last-Theorem,
    author = {K. Rubin and A. Silverberg},
    title = {{Wiles's Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem}},
    year = 2018,
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem&oldid=830454832},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

My changes to the `.bib` were

1. I added braces around your titles so they are exactly as you wrote them. (Whether or not that's what you want, depends on the formatting requirements of the document you're writing. I typically only add braces around proper nouns and let the `.bst` lowercase the rest of the words.)
2. I removed the unnecessary braces around your years.
3. I think you want an en dash between Taniyama and Shimura, so I added that.